# Why would some Windows executables not have a "Digital Signatures" tab?

Tags: windows, digital-signature

Why would some executable on a Windows 7 system not have a "Digital Signatures" tab?

(With this question I am referring to those executables that are not part of Windows OS and to which the installation package creates a shortcut in the start menu.)

Is it because:

1. The .exe file is actually some kind of a wrapper for e.g. Java Jar or Flash SWF files?
2. The manufacturer never digitally certified the .exe?
3. Some other reason?

I am asking because I thought that if the reason is #2 (that the binary was never certified by a CA) then I would have gotten some kind of warning message when installing the software.

**Update:** Below screen shot shows two executables on my machine. For one of them ("iClone.exe") Windows does not display the "Digital Signatures" tab. For the other one the tab is displayed.

[image: an .exe without a Dig Sign tab]

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the properties for the binaries and not the shortcuts?

Comment: Hi @NeilSmithline, yes the file is an .exe (or at least it is displayed as such). I have added a screen shot with more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Executable's are not *required* by Microsoft to be signed. However, drivers are.

> Starting with 64-bit versions of Windows Vista and later versions of
>   Windows, **driver code signing policy requires that all *driver code* have
>   a digital signature**. In addition, certain configurations of 32-bit
>   versions of Windows Vista and later versions of Windows also require
>   driver code to be digitally-signed in order to access next generation
>   premium content that is controlled by the content protection policy.
>   Windows Vista and later versions of Windows rely on digital signatures
>   of these components to increase the safety and stability of the
>   Microsoft Windows platform and enable new customer experiences with
>   next generation premium content.

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548231(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The signing requirement can be disabled on boot. E.g. https://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/

Comment: @k1DBLITZ Can you kindly check this question please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72709498/innosetup-code-signin-not-applying-for-all-the-files-how-to-fix-that

Answer (score 6):

If you find this for Microsoft executables, the reason is the implementation of Windows Explorer: Windows Explorer will only show digital signatures if the signature is in the executable itself (e.g. signed with `signtool`). It will not show digital signature that are stored in the Windows digital signatures catalog (`C:\Windows\System32\catroot\`) (e.g. generated with `makecat`).

To check an exectuable's signature including the entries from the digital signature catalog, use [SysInternals SigCheck](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx). It'll also tell you where it found the signature when run with the `-i` command line switch, e.g.

```
C:\>sigcheck.exe -i c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

Sigcheck v2.1 - File version and signature viewer
Copyright (C) 2004-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe:
        Verified:       Signed
        Catalog:        C:\Windows\system32\CatRoot\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}\Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-base~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0.cat
[...]
```

Answer (score 3):

> 2. The manufacturer never digitally certified the .exe?

Yes. It costs money and means extra effort in the deployment workflow.

> I am asking because I thought that if the reason is #2 (that the binary was never certified by a CA) then I would have gotten some kind of warning message when installing the software.

No. While you can configure similar things with "AppLocker" (I guess by using a [publisher allow-rule with condition "Any Publisher"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994621.aspx)), there is no such mechanism active by default on any Windows OS that I know of.